$p$-torsion related to algebraic groups
Definition $14.14$ from "Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type" by Malle and Testerman:
A prime $p$ is a torsion prime for a linear algebraic group $G$ if the fundamental group of some subsystem subgroup of $G$ has $p$-torsion.
But they didn't define $p$-torsion. Is this $p$-torsion the $p$-torsion subgroup of some abelian group? Thanks!

Would just be times $Z_p$, right?

Yes, it is the $p$-torsion subgroup of the fundamental group, which is abelian.

Since this seems, by your response, to be the answer to your question, I will post it as such: the fundamental group of a semisimple group is commutative (though I used it in my comment, I try to stay away from "Abelian" when speaking of linear algebraic groups!), and the definition refers to $p$-torsion in this commutative group in the usual sense of the term.
